# spring boot resttemplate api call by providing userid and password

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, resttemplate

I want to get data from another application controller by providing userid and password.

Getting Error- HTTP Error 405 (Method Not Allowed)

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String plainCreds = "USER1:password";
byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);

HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
ResponseEntity<String> response1 = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);

System.out.println("Result--------"+ response1.toString());
```

Comment: Please elaborate more. If you are getting any error then please post the error stack trace. It's not clear whether you are demonstrating code or asking for help.

Comment: is showing HTTP Error 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: Ditch this code, and use the `BasicAuthenticationInterceptor` instead. This will simplify your code (and you should be using the `RestTEmplateBuilder` to construct the `RestTEmplate` and define it as an `@Bean`. THen you can use `getForEntity` instead of exchange. The 405 means that the endpoint doesn't support GET, do you have the correct URL.

Comment: Are you sure that the API you are calling is a GET request? 
405 usually comes when there is a mismatch in the Http method.

Comment: if i am trying POST method it showing UNAUTHORIZED ACCESS 1   and print  Result----<302,[Location:"/TicketingSystem/Index.html", Content-Length:"0", Date:"Mon, 18 Nov 2019 12:57:01 GMT"]>@M.Deinum

Comment: Are you using the correct userid and passsword? Also please use the aformentioned interceptor or at least `HttpHeaders.setBasicAuth` .